# creating a foreign key like relationship with custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am currently building a website, that is heavily reliant on custom post types, 2 of my custom post types are "Clients" and "Case Studies", now what I am wanting is a way to create a dropdown in the "Case Studies" custom post type so that I can select from the Clients that have already been added to the site? Is this possible, I assume it would be similar creating a relationship in database, and then pulling in the clients from the clients and table and placing them in a `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create relationships between posts / pages with the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin. (more info on the [wiki](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki))

You could then [create a connexion](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage) between `Case Studies` and `Clients`, and associate them accordingly.

For clarity, you should ask your second question in a separate question, as it is not related to the title of this thread.